# How to access a command line application's bundle in C

Tags: c, xcode, macos, command-line

I am on a Mac, programming with Xcode.  I have a command line application that will read/write to files in it's bundle and I was wondering how to access these files.

Thanks,
       Mr. Man

EDIT: Would it work better if I just made a folder in the user's library folder?

Comment: Command line tools aren't normally bundles - can you tell us some more about the application structure?

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to *write* to files in your bundle, as you'll run into permissions problems in a lot of cases. Reading should be OK though.

Comment: For a commandline app, the directory the executable is in is the bundle directory. You can set up a `Copy Files` step in xcode. I'm not sure if this is documented though as I found it by trial and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you actually have a bundle, you can use the CoreFoundation [CFBundle API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/index.html). You can use `CFBundleGetMainBundle()` to find your app's bundle and the `CFBundleCopy*URL()` functions to get the URL of the bundle and its various components.

However, applications should not write to their bundles. There are a number of things that can go wrong with that, such as the current user not having write permission or a signed bundle getting broken. Generally, your application should put files it creates that aren't meant to be user-editable* in the ~/Library/Application Support folder. The normal place for user documents is the Documents folder.

(* To clarify "user editable," I mean files that the user is normally expected to navigate to and open himself rather than simply being a private store for data that's solely accessed through your app's interface. So for example TextEdit documents go in Documents while Stickies notes go in Application Support.)

Comment: ok, so what should I do with files that ARE supposed to be user-editable?

Comment: But don't have your app automatically dump files into `~/Documents` -- it's kind of rude to clutter the user's `Documents` folder.

Comment: @mipadi: would it be ok to make a folder in the user's documents folder and work from there?

Comment: Preferably the user should be able to choose where documents go.

Comment: @Mr.Man: If your app *has* to automatically create files, they should go under `~/Library/Application Support`; otherwise, let the user choose where to put them.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understand you question,
but if you want the path of one of your resources you can use:

```
NSString *path = (NSString*)[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"png"];
```

If you just want the app directory you could use:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] retain];
```

or

```
NSArray *resPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *resourceDirectory = [[resPaths objectAtIndex:0] retain];
```

I'm not at my Mac right now, so I'm just pasting from our framework.

Comment: Note: We actually build our command line tools as normal app bundles.

Comment: OK, I have used these in Objective-C but my program is in C, would your second and third ones work with regular C arrays?

Comment: @Carl usually just with the full path inside the bundle (".../osx.app/Contents/MacOS/main").